# How to get number of rows and columns of Gtk::Grid?

Tags: gtk, gtkmm

I want to get number of rows and columns of Gtk::Grid. But Gtk::Grid has no member function for it so I can't it. How to get number of rows and columns?

Comment: What version of Gtkmm are you using?

Comment: mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3 3.24.5-2

Comment: I see nothing to get this directly from the API. Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49756058/get-number-of-columns-in-gtk-grid